# Variable overwritten by ajax response

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoder

Using Google Maps and the Geocoder, I'm trying to loop over an object of addresses, return LatLng addresses for them, and create markers using both the original details and the latlng address in the `setMarker` function below.

The problem is, the `response[a]` is being overwritten by the last address in the object, because the for loop is running ahead of the AJAX results being returned.

How can I save the data in the current `response[a]` being looped over, so that when `setMarker()` is later called, it contains the right information?

Thanks

```
          var limit = 0;

          for (a in response){

            if(limit<5){ // limit API calls

                  var addr = [response[a].Addr1, response[a].City, response[a].Zip];

                  geo = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                  geo.geocode({
                    address: addr.join(", "),
                    componentRestrictions: {
                    //  country: 'UK'
                    }
                  }, function (results, status) {

                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results) {

                        var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                        var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                        if(latitude!="" && longitude!=""){

                            bounds.extend(latlng);
                            map.fitBounds(bounds);
                            _this.setMarker(map, limit, latlng, response[a]);

                        }

                    } // if geo results

              });

            }

            limit++;

          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is a classic one that can be solved using closure function.

Current code looks something like :

```
var a[20];

for(i=0;i<20;i++) {
    some_async_method() {
        //code that uses 'a[i]'
    }
}
```

Using closure to preserve the scope of var a inside a async function :

```
var a[20];

for(i=0;i<20;i++) {
    (function(_a){
        some_async_method() {
            //code that uses 'a[i]' as '_a'
        }   
    })(a[i]);// self calling function that preserves the scope of a[i]
}
```

**So your code will look like :**

```
var limit = 0;

for (a in response){

if(limit<5){ // limit API calls

      var addr = [response[a].Addr1, response[a].City, response[a].Zip];

      geo = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      (function(response_a){ // closure function to preserve scope of 'response[a]' 
          geo.geocode({
            address: addr.join(", "),
            componentRestrictions: {
            //  country: 'UK'
            }
          }, function (results, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results) {

                var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                if(latitude!="" && longitude!=""){

                    bounds.extend(latlng);
                    map.fitBounds(bounds);
                    _this.setMarker(map, limit, latlng, response_a);

                }

            } // if geo results

      });
    })(response[a]);

}

limit++;

}
```

Comment: you beautiful person. (I had to fix the typo for `reponse_a` but otherwise that's worked amazingly.. and I learnt something) thank you very much.